Can you make an ID map for scattered objects?
Basically I have assets that are scattered across a map (with the scatter add-on) and my programmers need an ID map to identify each asset separately. I'm new to Blender, but the way I would approach this in maya would probably be to do a "separate object" command and then to automatically generate my ID map. What would be the process on Blender and how can I execute it?
Thank you!
